# How do I scale an image in CSS on Qualtrics?

Tags: css, graphic, qualtrics

I'm using Qualtrics and I need to scale an image to run across the top of the survey page. 
I have scaled the question text / survey page size to be 80% of the screen using the code below:

`.Skin .SkinInner {
width:80%;
}`

But can't seem to find how to do so for a graphic / image file uploaded onto Qualtrics?

Could anybody clear this up?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to size these is to use the width and height properties.

For example:

```
<img src="*" width="100px" height="150px">
```

or alternatively you may hvae an image with an id or class such as:

```
<img src="*" class="className">
```

In this case you can set the width/height in the css, like so:

```
.className{
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
}
```